# Flutter -TextField Controller gets my cursor before Text

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I get this warnings on my Console 

`W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25185): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25185): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25185): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection`

I am using dateTime keyboard, when I enter text in textfield the cursor moves before the Text. This is annoying. I read somewhere that the TextEditing controller needs to be disposed/ closed. I am not sure how and what does that mean. Any one knows how to do away with these warnings and weird behavior on the TextInputController.

Comment: Sorry for reopening this question, but did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

i have same problem, 
**My Task**
i want to clear my textfield on button click

here is my code

```
String searchData = "";
 TextEditingController searchEditor = TextEditingController();

            Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(  // My textbox
                      controller: searchEditor,
                      autofocus: false,
                      onChanged: (str){
                        searchData = (str == null)? "" : str;
                        setState(() {
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: IconTheme(
                          child: Icon(Icons.search),
                          data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                        ),
                        labelText: 'Search',
                      ),
                    ),
                    flex: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Basic.hbColor,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      onPressed: (){      // On button click
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();   // Close keyboard
                        setState(() {
                          searchData = "";
                        });
                        Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 500),(){   //call back after 500  microseconds
                          searchEditor.clear();  // clear textfield 
                        });
                      },
                      elevation: 10,
                    ),
                    flex: 2,
                  )
                ],
              )
```

i solved by **USING  'searchEditor.clear();'   inside Future.delayed**
Because when we call  **FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();** for closing keyboard it take some microseconds for close that's why it show this **WANRING** 
i.e. `getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection`
to overcome i called searchEditor.clear(); method after some microseconds

**it's work for me.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to minimize/close the keyboard before pressing the Button, if you do so you will not get any warning.

Comment: Could you be more specific and show us how to do it in Flutter?

Answer (score -2):

you need to create variable first

```
<<< var _controller = TextEditingController(); >>>
```

then you create properties of textfield and pass it

```
<<<controller: _controller,>>>
```

then when your things done do it

```
<<<_controller.clear();>>>
```